# Resharper suppresses some Javascript intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, resharper, resharper-9.0

In my NodeJS app, when I am using ReSharper 9.2 (Ultimate 2015.2) in VS 2015 Enterprise, I have trouble with missing intellisense options.
I have two files: Javascript.js and Javascript1.js.

Javascript.js is as follows:

```
(function (cars) {
    cars.allCars = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
}
)(module.exports)
```

In Javascript1.js, when ReSharper is suspended, I get some helpful suggestions like "forEach": 
[image]

But when I'm using ReSharper, it looks like this: 
[image]

Even though when I hover over the "allCars" property of "cars" I am shown that it's an array, I don't get the expected "forEach" suggestion, or any of the other methods expected for an array.

I've verified I have all ReSharper updates. I've tried tweaking ReSharper settings and reviewing other question here in SO. Nothing I've found helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't support NodeJS modules resolution yet (that's why currently you have dynamic completion in this case). It's planned for one of the next versions. You're welcome to upvote and watch corresponding issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-273158.

At the meantime, you can also try WebStorm IDE, also from JetBrains, which already has NodeJS support built-in.